# Authorizing Grafana / Elasticsearch requests with JSON web tokens?

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, authorization, jwt, grafana

I have a Grafana dashboard running which uses Elasticsearch as a datasource. My goal is to embed panels from the dashboard in my web app using iframes.

Authorization on the web app is accomplished through JWTs, so when a user logs in, they receive a token from a server. I want to supply the token to each Grafana request (in this case, the embeddable link) and then check that the token is valid before processing the request.

Does this make sense to do? If so, what is the best or recommended way for me to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid making changes to Grafana itself you could use a reverse proxy to validate the JWT (eg https://github.com/auth0/nginx-jwt) and provide headers compatible with Grafana's AuthProxy system (http://docs.grafana.org/tutorials/authproxy/)

The alternative would be to make a PR for Grafana (potentially inspired by [#9166](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/9166)) that allows it to natively validate a JWT token and use it to log a user in.  That would be somewhat more involved though.

Comment: Thanks. The nginx solution seems reasonable. I am currently using Apache as my web server, so will investigate whether there is a mod for that.  I wanted to avoid going down the route of making changes to Grafana code.

Comment: https://github.com/AnthonyDeroche/mod_authnz_jwt seems like it should do the job for you, and the README describes how to specify a header with the authorized user name which is what the Grafana AuthProxy support requires.